# Pass argument to dockerfile @ runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

Basically want to be able to run a docker container with specified arguments

dockerfile:

```
FROM nodesource/node:4.0

ADD package.json package.json
RUN npm install
ADD . .

ENTRYPOINT ["node","index.js"]
```

I am essentially running the tutorial code found for rabbitMQ:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html

The only difference is, for me, instead of a hard coded Que name, i am using $args for it

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
var q = argv.que;
```

the cmd line way i run my nodejs is:
`node index.js --que 1`

and its working fine. however when executing from the `docker run` it doesn't seem to be working (args not read correctly)

i have tried:

`docker run -it mydockerimage --que (my queue name)`

but getting error:

> Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "--que":
>   executable file not found in $PATH.

What is the correct way for me to write this docker image so that i can pass in arguments at runtime?

I know i can do it by overriding the --entrypoint, but ideally i would like to type less...is this even possible?

Comment: Why not make it part of the environment? Then you can set a default in the Dockerfile or pass it in with `-e`.

Comment: Are you certain your image has the above entrypoint, and not a cmd? Check with `docker inspect mydockerimage`.

Comment: @BMitch yes, sure, because if i pass in 

`ENTRYPOINT ["node","index.js", "--que", "1"]`

it will work fine

Comment: Passing the full list to CMD would also work fine, but with your ENTRYPOINT set like that, you shouldn't be seeing the `--que` file not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` allows you to specify the default executable for your image while also providing default arguments to that executable which may be overridden by the user.

```
FROM nodesource/node:4.0

ADD package.json package.json
RUN npm install
ADD . .

ENTRYPOINT ["node","index.js"]
CMD ["--que","1"]
```

So, the default behaviour of `docker run` will be to send the argument `--que 1`

```
docker run -it mydockerimage
```

But you can override that value

```
docker run -it mydockerimage --que 2
```